# How to remove this numerical artifact?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve a differential equation:
$$\frac{d f}{d\theta} = \frac{1}{c}(\text{max}(\sin\theta, 0) - f^4)~,$$
subject to periodic boundary condition, whic would imply $f(0)=f(2\pi)$ and $f'(0)= f'(2\pi)$. To solve this numerically, I have set up an equation:
$$f_i = f_{i-1}+\frac{1}{c}(\theta_i-\theta_{i-1})\left(\max(\sin\theta_i,0)-f_{i-1}^4\right)~.$$ Now, I want to solve this for specific grids. Suppose, I set up my grid points in $\theta = (0, 2\pi)$ to be $n$ equally spaced floats. Then I have small python program which would calculate $f$ for each grid points in $\theta$. Here is the program:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n=100
m = 500
a = np.linspace(0.01, 2*np.pi, n)
b = np.linspace(0.01, 2*np.pi, m)
arr = np.sin(a)
arr1 = np.sin(b)
index = np.where(arr<0)
index1 = np.where(arr1<0)
arr[index] = 0
arr1[index1] = 0
epsilon = 0.03
final_arr_l = np.ones(arr1.size)
final_arr_n = np.ones(arr.size)
for j in range(1,100*arr.size):
    i = j%arr.size
    step = final_arr_n[i-1]+ 1./epsilon*2*np.pi/n*(arr[i] - final_arr_n[i-1]**4)
    if (step>=0):
        final_arr_n[i] = step
    else:
        final_arr_n[i] = 0.2*final_arr_n[i-1]
for j in range(1,100*arr1.size):
    i = j%arr1.size
    final_arr_l[i] = final_arr_l[i-1]+1./epsilon*2*np.pi/m*(arr1[i] - final_arr_l[i-1]**4)

plt.plot(b, final_arr_l)
plt.plot(a, final_arr_n)
plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

My major problem is for small $c$, in the above case when $c=0.03$, the numerical equation does not converge to a reasonable value (it is highly oscillatory) if I choose $N$ to be not so large. The main reason for that is since $\frac{1}{c}*(\theta_i-\theta_{i-1})>1$, $f$ tends to be driven to negative infinity when $N$ is not so large, i.e. $\theta_i-\theta_{i-1}$ is not so small. Here is an example with $c=0.03$ showing the behaviour when $N=100$ versus $N=500$. In my code, I have applied some adhoc criteria for small $N$ to avoid divergences:

```
step = final_arr_n[i-1]+ 1./epsilon*2*np.pi/n*(max(np.sin(a[i]), 0) - final_arr_n[i-1]**4)
if (step>=0):
    final_arr_n[i] = step
else:
    final_arr_n[i] = 0.2*final_arr_n[i-1]
```

**what I would like to know: is there any good mathematical trick to solve this numerical equation with not so large $N$ and still make it converge for small $c$?**

[image]

Comment: Should probably move this to the computational science site, https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ because some angry pure mathematician will close it.

Comment: Why is there a subtraction in $f_i = f_{i-1}-c(\theta_i-\theta_{i-1})\left(\max(\sin\theta_i,0)-f_{i-1}^4\right)$? I would have instead expected $f_i = f_{i-1} + c(\theta_i-\theta_{i-1})\left(\max(\sin\theta_i,0)-f_{i-1}^4\right)$. Am I missing something or is it just a typo?

Comment: Another question: If the interval is $[0,2\pi]$ and $N=100$ then $\theta_j - \theta_{j-1} = 2\pi / N \approx 0.0628$. How is it for small $c$ we have $c \cdot (\theta_j - \theta_{j-1}) > 1$? I would only expect that issue for large $c$.

Comment: @Spencer You are totally right. There were two typos, first it must have been $f_i=f_{i-1}+c(\theta_i-\theta{i-1})...$, and next, the equation should have $1/c$  instead of $c$ (that is what I use in my code). So, for small $c$, the factor $1/c * (\theta_j-\theta_{j-1})$ could be larger than 1.

Comment: The most basic improvement you can make is to use a more stable method. You are applying the Euler method which is not very stable. Maybe try using the RK4 method or Adams-Bashforth and see what improvements you get. You will still need $N$ to be large, but maybe not so large. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods

http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/AdamsBashforthMod.html

Comment: @Spencer. Thank you for your suggestion. I did try with the methods you mentioned, but it doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: I am not sure @Shogun's advice was correct, but in any case, [please do not have multiple copies of the question open on different sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/152819). If you think [the question on scicomp.stackexchange.com](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/31481/3883) fits better, then delete the question here, and vice versa.

Comment: Reading the plot, the exact solution is bounded by $|f|<1.2$. This gives a local Lipschitz constant of $L=\frac1c4\max|f|^3\sim \frac{8}c$. The Euler method is not horribly unstable for $Lh<2$ and somewhat stable for $Lh<1$ or $h<0.125\cdot 0.03$ or $N>2\pi\cdot 250>1500$. So one would still need some kind of error estimation to test the reliability of the $N=500$ result.

Comment: On a first order equation you can only impose one boundary condition. That the first derivative is the same follows from periodicity, the right side gets evaluated in the same point.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3185707/115115 for the same problem with an unspecific question for numerical methods in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to solve this (perhaps a little more complicated than necessary) with the tools of python `scipy.integrate` I demonstrated in [How to numerically set up to solve this differential equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3185707/115115)

---

If you want to stay with the simplicity of a one-stage method, expand the step as $f(t+s)=f(t)+h(s)$ where $t$ is constant and $s$ the variable, so that
$$
εh'(s)=εf'(t+s)=g(t+s)-f(t)^4-4f(t)^3h(s)-6f(t)^2h(s)^2-...
$$
The factor linear in $h$ can be moved to and integrated into the left side by an exponential integrating factor. The remaining terms are quadratic or of higher degree in $h(Δt)\simΔt$ and thus do not influence the order of the resulting exponential-Euler method.
\begin{align}
ε\left(e^{4f(t)^3s/ε}h(s)\right)'&=e^{4f(t)^3s/ε}\left(g(t+s)-f(t)^4-6f(t)^2h(s)^2-...\right)
\\
\implies 
h(Δt)&\approx h(0)e^{-4f(t)^3Δt/ε}+\frac{1-e^{-4f(t)^3Δt/ε}}{4f(t)^3}\left(g(t)-f(t)^4\right)
\\
\implies 
f(t+Δt)&\approx f(t)+\frac{1-e^{-4f(t)^3Δt/ε}}{4f(t)^3}\left(g(t)-f(t)^4\right)
\end{align}

This can be implemented as

```
eps = 0.03

def step(t,f,dt):
# exponential Euler step
    g = max(0,np.sin(t))
    f3 = 4*f**3;
    ef = np.exp(-f3*dt/eps)
    return f + (1-ef)/f3*(g - f**4)

# plot the equilibrium curve f(t)**4 = max(0,sin(t))
x = np.linspace(0,np.pi, 150);
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x)**0.25,c="lightgray",lw=5)
plt.plot(2*np.pi-x,0*x,c="lightgray",lw=5)

for N in [500, 100, 50]:
    a0, a1 = 0, eps/2
    t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,N+1)
    dt = t[1]-t[0];
    while abs(a0-a1)>1e-6:
        # Aitken delta-squared method to accelerate the fixed-point iteration
        f = a0 = a1;
        for n in range(N): f = step(t[n],f,dt);
        a1 = f;
        if abs(a1-a0) < 1e-12: break
        for n in range(N): f = step(t[n],f,dt);
        a2 = f;
        a1 = a0 - (a1-a0)**2/(a2+a0-2*a1)
    # produce the function table for the numerical solution
    f = np.zeros_like(t)
    f[0] = a1;
    for n in range(N): f[n+1] = step(t[n],f[n],dt);
    plt.plot(t,f,"-o", lw=2, ms=2+200.0/N, label="N=%4d"%N)

plt.grid(); plt.legend(); plt.show()
```

and gives the plot

[image]

showing stability even for $N=50$. The errors for smaller $N$ look more chaotic due to the higher non-linearity of the method.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not told to do it all by yourself, I would suggest you to use the powerful `scipy` package (specially the [`integrate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/tutorial/integrate.html) subpackage) which exposes many useful objects and methods to [solve ODE](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html#solving-initial-value-problems-for-ode-systems).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

First define your model:

```
def model(t, y, c=0.03):
    return (np.max([np.sin(t), 0]) - y**4)/c
```

Then choose and instantiate the ODE Solver of your choice (here I have chosen [BDF](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.BDF.html#scipy.integrate.BDF) solver):

```
t0 = 0
tmax = 10
y0 = np.array([0.35]) # You should compute the boundary condition more rigorously
ode = integrate.BDF(model, t0, y0, tmax)
```

The [new API](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp) of ODE Solver allows user to control integration step by step:

```
t, y = [], []
while ode.status == 'running':
    ode.step() # Perform one integration step
    # You can perform all desired check here...
    # Object contains all information about the step performed and the current state! 
    t.append(ode.t)
    y.append(ode.y)
ode.status # finished
```

Notice the [old API](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html#scipy.integrate.odeint) is still present, but gives less control on the integration process:

```
t2 = np.linspace(0, tmax, 100)
sol = integrate.odeint(model, y0, t2, tfirst=True)
```

And now requires the switch `tfirst` set to true because `scipy` swapped variable positions in model signature when creating the new API.

Both result are compliant and seems to converge for the given setup:

```
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.plot(t, y, label="BDF")
axe.plot(t2, sol, '+', label="odeint")
axe.set_title(r"ODE: $\frac{d f}{d\theta} = \frac{1}{c}(\max(\sin\theta, 0) - f^4)$")
axe.set_xlabel("$t$")
axe.set_ylabel("$y(t)$")
axe.set_ylim([0, 1.2])
axe.legend()
axe.grid()
```

[image]

Solving ODE numerically is about choosing a suitable integration method (stable, convergent) and well setup the parameters.

I have observed that [RK45](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html#scipy.integrate.RK45) also performs well for this problem and requires less steps than BDF for your setup. Up to you to choose the Solver which suits you best.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3185707/115115 where I used `scipy.integrate.solve_bvp` to properly solve this as boundary-value problem.

Comment: @LutzL, I was not totally awake this morning. I solved the IVP instead of BVP, thank you for noticing, I will update my post soon.